# if $ a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$ , $a_n =?$ Case 1

Tags: real-analysis, induction

> Find and prove by induction an explicit formula for $a_n$ if $a_1=1$ and, for $n \geq 1$,
>
> $$P_n:  a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

let's check when $n=1$ => $a_1=1$  (given)

let's assume that $P_n$ is true $ \forall n \geq 1$

I claim that $P_{n+1}$ is true:

$$P_{n+1}:  a_{n+2}= \frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+2)(2n+3)}$$

Substituting $a_{n+1}$ for $a_n$:

$$P_{n+1}:  a_{n+2}= \frac{\frac{a_n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}}{(n+2)(2n+3)}$$

I am puzzled at this level, am i going in the right direction? is there a more efficient approach?

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: $$\frac{a_0}{n!(2n-1)!!}$$

Comment: Before going into a proof by induction, you need to know what is the forumal you're trying to establish. $P_n$ is the recurrence formula, but you want to prove something like $a_n=f(n)$. To have an idea about the function $f()$ you may start by calculating $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ and see if some pattern appears... Otherwise, from your start, you may write everything with only one fraction bar and go on with $a_{n+3}$...

Comment: what you did does not count as explicit. Try to find $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$ first and see how they relate to $2,3,4$ respectively. Try to guess how $a_n$ depends on $n$ directly (not on $a_{n-1}$). If you come up with a correct guess, try to prove it by induction. It looks someone @polfosol did all that quickly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial for the $!!$ notation :)

Comment: `am i going in the right direction?` Not sure about that. You are given the recurrence, and are asked to find and prove `an explicit formula`. For a simpler example, if instead you were given $a_{n+1}=a_n/(n+1)$ then you would be expected to find $a_n = a_1 / n!\,$.

Comment: No, you are not.  You have a definition and that you are given so you are not claiming anything to prove.  It is asking you to find an expression $a_n = f(n) = something-to-do-with-n$ such as $a_n = 27n^3 + \sqrt {3n}$ and then prove that by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from an arbitrary $n$ will not help you find the general pattern if you are not familiar with such a kind of recurrence. In this case, you'd better start with the first terms.

$$a_1=1,\\a_2=\frac1{2\cdot3},\\a_3=\frac1{2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot5},\\a_4=\frac1{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7},\\a_5=\frac1{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9},\\\cdots$$

Now it should be clear that the denominators are the products of all integers from $1$ to $n$ and all odd integers from $1$ to $2n-1$.

This is written

$$a_n=\frac1{n!(2n-1)!!}.$$

---

Proof by induction:

$$a_1=\frac1{1!1!!}=1$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac1{(n+1)!(2n+1)!!}=\frac1{n!(n+1)(2n-1)!!(2n+1)}=\frac{a_n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = a_1\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} = a_1\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{(k+1)(2k+1)} = a_1\prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k}\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2k-1} = a_1\cdot\dfrac{1}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)!!}$$

Note that $m!! \neq (m!)!$ but the [double factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: There is no $a_0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited just now.